# Symfony2 entity choice list set selected object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There are two entities, **Category** and **Device**. A device can be related to exactly one category. A category can be related to many devices.

I use following custom form type to create and edit a device:

```
class DeviceFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MySupportBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'name'
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'device';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'My\SupportBundle\Entity\Device',
        );
    }

}
```

So basically each device has a name and is assign to one category. This works fine. Now when I try to edit the device and change the category, in the choice list the current category is not selected:

```
 public function editDeviceAction($id, Request $request) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $device = $em->getRepository('MySupportBundle:Device')->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(new DeviceFormType(), $device);

        $valid = false;

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $device = $form->getData();
                $device->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('view_shop'));
            } else {
                $valid = true;
            }
        } else {
            $valid = true;
        }

        return $this->render('MySupportBundle:Shop:editDevice.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'valid' => $valid,
                    'device' => $device
                ));
    }
```

Any ideas how to set the category as selected?

Device:

```
<entity name="My\SupportBundle\Entity\Device" table="device">   
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
                <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one field="category" target-entity="Category"/>

        <field name="name" column="name" type="string" length="255"/>     
</entity>
```

Category:

```
<entity name="My\SupportBundle\Entity\Category" table="category">   
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>

    <one-to-many field="device" target-entity="Device" mapped-by="Device"/>

    <field name="name" column="name" type="string" length="255"/>              
</entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by myself.

Obviously when creating form view like this

```
{{ form_widget(form.type)}}
```

and in form type like this

```
    $builder->add('type', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'name'
    ));
```

it won't work. Because "type" is wrong. It has to be "category" instead of "type". Very strange but this was the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure but are you checking the relationship One-To-Many and Many-to-One?They are uni-directional or bidirictinal?You can show us your Device and Category Entity Classes...

Comment: I guess in your entity classes all is good,on the other hand you make var_dump($device) when u use find($id) and you see What it will return as a result because u have a problem in this line...

Answer (score 1):

You are using a custom repository method called `find()` - depending on how you overloaded it,  `Category` may not have been fetched. You can rely on default `findOneById(int $id)` method.

Comment: Updating an entity you do not need the call persist. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object

Comment: @ArtWorkAD I know, I'm just guessing your query doesn't feature an explicit join on `Category` entity so it results as null.